# PHP read_exif_data and Adjust Orientation

Tags: php, orientation, exif

I am using the following code to rotate an uploaded jpeg image if the orientation is off.  I am only having problems with images uploaded from iPhones and Android.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $upload_path . $newfilename)){
            chmod($upload_path . $newfilename, 0755);
            $exif = exif_read_data($upload_path . $newfilename);
            $ort = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
            switch($ort)
            {

                case 3: // 180 rotate left
                    $image->imagerotate($upload_path . $newfilename, 180, -1);
                    break;


                case 6: // 90 rotate right
                    $image->imagerotate($upload_path . $newfilename, -90, -1);
                    break;

                case 8:    // 90 rotate left
                    $image->imagerotate($upload_path . $newfilename, 90, -1);
                    break;
            }
            imagejpeg($image, $upload_path . $newfilename, 100);
            $success_message = 'Photo Successfully Uploaded';
        }else{
            $error_count++;
            $error_message = 'Error: Upload Unsuccessful<br />Please Try Again';
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong with the way I am reading the EXIF data from the jpeg?  It is not rotating the images as it is supposed to.

This is what happens when I run a var_dump($exif);

```
array(41) {
    ["FileName"]=> string(36) "126e7c0efcac2b76b3320e6187d03cfd.JPG"
    ["FileDateTime"]=> int(1316545667)
    ["FileSize"]=> int(1312472)
    ["FileType"]=> int(2)
    ["MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["SectionsFound"]=> string(30) "ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF"
    ["COMPUTED"]=> array(8) {
        ["html"]=> string(26) "width="2048" height="1536""
        ["Height"]=> int(1536)
        ["Width"]=> int(2048)
        ["IsColor"]=> int(1)
        ["ByteOrderMotorola"]=> int(1)
        ["ApertureFNumber"]=> string(5) "f/2.8"
        ["Thumbnail.FileType"]=> int(2)
        ["Thumbnail.MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" }
        ["Make"]=> string(5) "Apple"
        ["Model"]=> string(10) "iPhone 3GS"
        ["Orientation"]=> int(6)
        ["XResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1"
            ["YResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1" ["ResolutionUnit"]=> int(2) ["Software"]=> string(5) "4.3.5" ["DateTime"]=> string(19) "2011:09:16 21:18:46" ["YCbCrPositioning"]=> int(1) ["Exif_IFD_Pointer"]=> int(194) ["THUMBNAIL"]=> array(6) { ["Compression"]=> int(6) ["XResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1" ["YResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1" ["ResolutionUnit"]=> int(2) ["JPEGInterchangeFormat"]=> int(658) ["JPEGInterchangeFormatLength"]=> int(8231) } ["ExposureTime"]=> string(4) "1/15" ["FNumber"]=> string(4) "14/5" ["ExposureProgram"]=> int(2) ["ISOSpeedRatings"]=> int(200) ["ExifVersion"]=> string(4) "0221" ["DateTimeOriginal"]=> string(19) "2011:09:16 21:18:46" ["DateTimeDigitized"]=> string(19) "2011:09:16 21:18:46" ["ComponentsConfiguration"]=> string(4) "" ["ShutterSpeedValue"]=> string(8) "3711/949" ["ApertureValue"]=> string(9) "4281/1441" ["MeteringMode"]=> int(1) ["Flash"]=> int(32) ["FocalLength"]=> string(5) "77/20" ["SubjectLocation"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1023) [1]=> int(767) [2]=> int(614) [3]=> int(614) } ["FlashPixVersion"]=> string(4) "0100" ["ColorSpace"]=> int(1) ["ExifImageWidth"]=> int(2048) ["ExifImageLength"]=> int(1536) ["SensingMethod"]=> int(2) ["ExposureMode"]=> int(0) ["WhiteBalance"]=> int(0) ["SceneCaptureType"]=> int(0) ["Sharpness"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Note that this code will recompress the source image, even if no rotation was needed.

Comment: My problem right now is that the images that need to be rotated are not being rotated.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($exif)` to see what the android phones are producing in the way of rotation data.

Comment: I have updated the post to include the var_dump of $exif

Comment: Ok, i cleaned up the dump there. Obviously. the orientation field is not in an 'IFD0' section, it's `$exif['COMPUTED']['Orientation']` and has value 6.

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason even with `$ort = $exif['COMPUTED']['Orientation'];` it is still not rotating the image as case 6 is satisfied.  Could the problem lie in `imagejpeg` as I have it set to overwrite the original file?

Comment: Well, definitely check what imagejpeg() returns - it'll return a boolean false on failure.

Comment: OK that kind of helped narrow the problem down... `imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource [file] => /www/students/touch/upload_picture.php [line]`. So for some reason it is not getting $image from the switch.

Comment: imagejpeg is for GD, but earlier on you're using $image in OOP context, which implies it's not a GD image handle.

Comment: Do you have a recommended fix for this? Thank you for all of your help.  I am still learning the ins and outs of PHP

Comment: Depends on what $image is and how you're setting it up. If you go pure GD, it'd be `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('/path/to/image'); $rotated = imagerotate($image, 90, 0); imagejpeg($rotated, '/path/to/rotated/file');`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Thank you for all of your help with this issue.  I have gotten it working with your help and suggestions.

Comment: $exif['Orientation']; is working fine for me. It might be a better choice comparing to $exif['some_section']['Orientation'];

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The documentation for [imagerotate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) refers to a different type for the first parameter than you use:

> An image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions,
> such as imagecreatetruecolor().

Here is a small example for using this function:

```
function resample($jpgFile, $thumbFile, $width, $orientation) {
    // Get new dimensions
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($jpgFile);
    $height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig);
    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgFile);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    // Fix Orientation
    switch($orientation) {
        case 3:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
            break;
        case 8:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
            break;
    }
    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, $thumbFile, 90);
}
```

Comment: From some reason, images created by android 4.1.2 does not need to be rotated, only load the image by "imagecreatefromjpen()" and then just save it back with "imagejpeg()". Do you know why?

Answer (score 87):

Based on Daniel's code I wrote a function that simply rotates an image if necessary, without resampling.

## GD

```
function image_fix_orientation(&$image, $filename) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    
    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;
            
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;
            
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### One line version (GD)

```
function image_fix_orientation(&$image, $filename) {
    $image = imagerotate($image, array_values([0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, -90, 0, 90])[@exif_read_data($filename)['Orientation'] ?: 0], 0);
}
```

## ImageMagick

```
function image_fix_orientation($image) {
    if (method_exists($image, 'getImageProperty')) {
        $orientation = $image->getImageProperty('exif:Orientation');
    } else {
        $filename = $image->getImageFilename();
        
        if (empty($filename)) {
            $filename = 'data://image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($image->getImageBlob());
        }
        
        $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
        $orientation = isset($exif['Orientation']) ? $exif['Orientation'] : null;
    }
    
    if (!empty($orientation)) {
        switch ($orientation) {
            case 3:
                $image->rotateImage('#000000', 180);
                break;
            
            case 6:
                $image->rotateImage('#000000', 90);
                break;
            
            case 8:
                $image->rotateImage('#000000', -90);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Imagick I use getImageOrientation() to retrieve the orientation and then after rotating the image I set the correct Exif Orientation value via $image->setImageOrientation(\Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);

Comment: Do you have a solution for WideImage?

Comment: In some cases the imagick function `getImageOrientation()` did not work for me correctly even with converted raw images. The code above worked perfectly.

Comment: In first version (GD) what should I pass for &$image where I am calling this function?

Comment: for whom does not understand how to pass &$image parameter from the local file, use like that :
      

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($local_filename);
image_fix_orientation($im, $local_filename);
if ($im) {
    imagejpeg($im, $local_filename);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

Comment: This is much better in case the file isn't a jpeg

Comment: For me, the rotation for `case 6` and `case 8` should be swapped. That is `case 6 = -90` and `case 8 = 90`.

Answer (score 48):

Simpler function for those uploading an image, it just autorotates if necessary.

```
function image_fix_orientation($filename) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;

            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;

            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                break;
        }

        imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);
    }
}
```

Comment: Made this answer into a simple composer package, which can be found on github (class with only one method): https://github.com/diversen/image-auto-rotate

Comment: You use the wrong degree values. In case 6 you need 90 and in case 8 you need -90 degree.

Comment: very useful function, if anyone see this warning **Illegal IFD size** you can use the [@ operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) **e.g** :  `$exif = @exif_read_data($filename);`

Comment: @user462990 This function works well but for only images served locally. How will 
 one go about passing an image url? I have an image on s3 that I needed to manipulate  the orientation.

Answer (score 29):

Why is nobody considering mirrored cases 2,4,5,7? 
There are 4 more cases in exif orientation land:

[image]

Here is a complete solution taking a filename:

```
function __image_orientate($source, $quality = 90, $destination = null)
{
    if ($destination === null) {
        $destination = $source;
    }
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
        $exif = exif_read_data($source);
        if (!empty($exif['Orientation']) && in_array($exif['Orientation'], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])) {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [3, 4])) {
                $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
            }
            if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [5, 6])) {
                $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            }
            if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [7, 8])) {
                $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            }
            if (in_array($exif['Orientation'], [2, 5, 7, 4])) {
                imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
            }
            imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. This was a good point because many users upload mirrored images and they have problems with their final image.

Comment: This problem is very wrong. The "PHP team" did it by half? This seems like a solution.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone comes across this. From what I can make out some of the switch statements above are wrong.

Based on information [here](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html), it should be:

```
switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($image, -180, 0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
        break;
    case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
        break;
}
```

Comment: They were indeed incorrect. I edited them and they should be correct now.

Comment: At least case 6 is still wrong for me

Answer (score 6):

It's probably worthwhile to mention that if you are using ImageMagick from command line, you can use the [-auto-orient](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option which will auto rotate the image based on the existing EXIF orientation data.

```
convert -auto-orient /tmp/uploadedImage.jpg /save/to/path/image.jpg
```

Please note: If the EXIF data was stripped before the process, it will not work as described.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to chime in with yet another set of orientation values, but in my experience using any of the values listed above, I always ended up with upside down images when uploading portrait orientation shots directly from an iPhone. Here's the switch statement I ended up with.

```
switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image, -180, 0);
            break;

        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;

        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I'am explaining the whole thing, I use Laravel and use the Image Intervention Package.

First of all, I get my image and send it to my another function for resizing and some other functionality, if we do not need this, you can skip...

Grab the file with a method in my controller,

```
 public  function getImageFile(Request $request){
    $image = $request->image;
    $this->imageUpload($image);
}
```

Now, I send it to resize and getting the image name and extension...

```
public function  imageUpload($file){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $directory = 'uploads/';
    $name = str_replace([" ", "."], "_", $file->getClientOriginalName()) . "_";
    $file_name = $name . time() . rand(1111, 9999) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //path set
    $img_url = $directory.$file_name;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $h = ($height/$width)*600;
    Image::make($file)->resize(600, $h)->save(public_path($img_url));
    $this->image_fix_orientation($file,$img_url);
    return $img_url;
}
```

Now I call my image orientation function,

```
 public function image_fix_orientation($file,$img_url ) {
    $data = Image::make($file)->exif();
    if (!empty($data['Orientation'])) {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        switch ($data['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;

            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                break;

            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;
        }

        imagejpeg($image, $img_url, 90);
    }

}
```

And That's all...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my PHP 7 function inspired by @user462990:

```
/**
 * @param string $filePath
 *
 * @return resource|null
 */
function rotateImageByExifOrientation(string $filePath)
{
    $result = null;

    $exif = exif_read_data($filePath);
    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
        if (is_resource($image)) {
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 3:
                    $result = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    $result = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    $result = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

usage:

```
    $rotatedFile = rotateImageByExifOrientation($absoluteFilePath);
    if (is_resource($rotatedFile)) {
        imagejpeg($rotatedFile, $absoluteFilePath, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

jhead -autorot jpegfile.jpg

Is also a useful way to approach this.

jhead is a standard program in Linux (use 'sudo apt-get install jhead' to install), this option looks at the orientation and rotates the image correctly and losslessly only if it requires. It then also updates the EXIF data correctly.

In this way you can process a jpeg (or multiple jpegs in a folder) in a simple one-pass way that fixes rotation issues permanently.

E.g: 
jhead -autorot *.jpg 
will fix a whole folder of jpeg images in just the manner the OP requires in the initial question.

While it's not technically PHP I did read this thread and then used my jhead suggestion instead, called from a PHP system() call to achieve the results I was after which were coincident with the OPs: to rotate images so any software (like 'fbi' in Raspbian) could display them correctly.

In light of this I thought others may benefit from knowing how easily jhead solves this problem and posted the information here only for informative purposes - because no one had mentioned it previously.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it was short.  Try explaining your solution in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

I've also used `orientate()` form Intervention, and it works flawlessly.

```
    $image_resize = Image::make($request->file('photo'));
    $image_resize->resize(1600, null,function ($constraint)
    {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $filename = $this->checkFilename();

    $image_resize->orientate()->save($this->photo_path.$filename,80);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer should be updated to take into account all possible exif orientation values (from 1 to 8):

```
function resample($jpgFile, $thumbFile, $width, $orientation) {
    // Get new dimensions
    list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($jpgFile);
    $height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig);
    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpgFile);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    // Fix Orientation
    switch($orientation) {
        case 3:
        case 4:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 5:
        case 6:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
            $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
            break;
    }
    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, $thumbFile, 90);
}
```

More information [here](https://sirv.com/help/articles/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/#exif-orientation-values).

Note that the image should be flipped for the following exif values: 2, 4, 6, and 8.

Answer (score -1):

[Intervention Image](https://image.intervention.io/) has a method [**`orientate()`**](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/orientate):

```
$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate();
```

> This method reads the EXIF image profile setting 'Orientation' and performs a rotation on the image to display the image correctly.