# ImpressPages 4 : upload photo auto-rotate

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, impresspages

I'm on IP 4.1.1.
I want to upload a photo (for photo or gallery widget for example).
I take a portrait photo (jpg) on my pc but when I upload it, it is in landscape format...

I try to use read_exif_data and imagerotate (like in this post : [PHP read_exif_data and Adjust Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation)) but it doesn't work.

An idea? Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: How exactly are you going this? And where it fails (getting data, reading file, rotating or updating the file)?

Comment: I drag and drop a widget (image or gallery) into the page.
I drag and drop (or click "add") my image. IP load the image (which is in portrait format on my pc) and i see it in landscape format on preview (where you select the image you want to add in page)...
I read that it doens't care to the format if we don't use exif... 
I don't find any solution...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first you are talking like an end user "upload photo ...". But then you say you are ysing read_exif_data function and other stuff which is a programming.

If we are talking about the end user interface. Most likely your photo is actually landscape, but has meta data about how the image has to be rotated before displaying it. In that case just rotate the image on your computer and reupload.