# Upload and rotate image based on EXIF data

Tags: php

Currently I am using this code to upload an image:

```
elseif ($_post['password'] == ''){
    if($my_form->checkEmail($_POST['email'])) { // check for good mail

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["img"]["name"]));

        if ((($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["img"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["img"]["size"] < 3145728)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
           if ($_FILES["img"]["error"] <= 0)
           {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $user->userID.'.'.$extension);
           }
        }
```

I am using this code to show the image (it grabs the last modified file):

```
 $avatars = glob("upload/$user->userID.*");
 if(!empty($avatars)) {
 $avatars = array_combine($avatars, array_map("filemtime", $avatars));
 arsort($avatars);
 $latest_avatar = key($avatars);

 echo '<img style="width:20%;" src="'.$latest_avatar.'">';
 echo '<p>**Note Image must be smaller than 3MB.</p>';
 echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>';
```

I have seen some code around and have tried to use it, but I cannot get it to work... something like this:

```
$avatars = glob("upload/$user->userID.*");
if(!empty($avatars)) {
$avatars = array_combine($avatars, array_map("filemtime", $avatars));
arsort($avatars);
$latest_avatar = key($avatars);

function resample($latest_avatar, $thumbFile, $width, $orientation) {
// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($latest_avatar);
$height = (int) (($width / $width_orig) * $height_orig);
// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image   = imagecreatefromjpeg($latest_avatar);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// Fix Orientation
switch($orientation) {
    case 3:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 180, 0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, -90, 0);
        break;
    case 8:
        $image_p = imagerotate($image_p, 90, 0);
        break;
}
// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, $thumbFile, 90);
}

echo '<img style="width:20%;" src="'.$image_p.'">';
echo '<p>**Note Image must be smaller than 3MB.</p>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>';
```

It comes out with nothing, img src is just blank. I get no errors... error reporting is enabled. If I take out the function and use `echo '<img style="width:20%;" src="'.$latest_avatar.'">';` it works fine and shows the image, but of course it isn't rotated.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: this will fail `$_post` for one thing (see what you have for email now?). Fix that and try it again. You should be getting an undefined variable notice, but you're not checking for errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: plus, hard to tell if your form's kosher or not

Comment: The form works fine... I can currently upload an image and everything else. I just need to rotate the image based on EXIF data, thanks.

Comment: ok, well technically `$_post['password']` should be `$_POST['password']` but that's probably irrelevant here. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Make sure you're calling the function also.

Comment: This Q&A should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/7489742/ not sure if that's where you got your code from though.

Comment: Th problem is, I'm confused as to where to put the function (I assume I could put it anywhere) and where to call the function. I'm not even sure if it is the right function that I should be using. I have error reporting enabled... I get no errors, it just never rotates the image.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13963783/ and seems there's an example on its usage. Seems to be the similar code as yours. May have to "echo" the function too.

Comment: I have read those for the past 2 days and I just don't understand. I will edit original post with how I have put it together...