# How can I fix iOS image orientation issues when uploading an image with php and after is has been uploaded

Tags: php

So, I am trying to find out how to fix images orientation when uploading them and after they have been uploaded. I hardly know how to get their exif information by doing this.

```
$image = img_dir .$ref['filename'];
$exif = exif_read_data($image, 0, true);
```

I use this line below to show the image orientation in a span.

```
<?= "" . $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'] . "\n"?>
```

Now, I am trying to use the image orientation to flip the image according to the orientation. For example: I have an image of a flower, and it has an orientation of "6", so I would like to get the image to rotate according to its number and then display it.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the solution below from [Lee Sherwood](https://github.com/leesherwood) to fix the orientation:

https://github.com/leesherwood/Orientation-Fix-PHP

> AKA: I couldn't care less what you do with it, im just a nice guy and i want to share. But it would be nice if you left me a little credit :)

Here is the main function that does the actual job.

Pass a string representing the image path and filename such as /var/www/images/image.jpg and it will change the name of the image to include "orig." (for the sake of not deleting your image if something goes wrong) and then create a new image with the same filename, with the orientation fixed

The return bool is not informative and should only be used to to tell your script that there is a proper orientated image available (or not). If you want to know why it failed (theres many reason) then you need to make the return values for informative, or use exceptions.

```
function fix_orientation($fileandpath){
// Does the file exist to start with?
if( !file_exists( $fileandpath ) )
    return false;
// Get all the exif data from the file
// By @kormanowsky: I used '@' to prevent annoying warnings
$exif = @read_exif_data( $fileandpath, 'IFD0' );
// If we dont get any exif data at all, then we may as well stop now
if( !$exif || !is_array( $exif ) )
    return false;
// I hate case juggling, so we're using loweercase throughout just in case
$exif = array_change_key_case( $exif, CASE_LOWER );
// If theres no orientation key, then we can give up, the camera hasn't told us the
// orientation of itself when taking the image, and i'm not writing a script to guess at it!
if( !array_key_exists( 'orientation', $exif ) )
    return false;
// Gets the GD image resource for loaded image
$img_res = get_image_resource( $fileandpath );
// If it failed to load a resource, give up
if( is_null( $img_res ) )
    return false;
// The meat of the script really, the orientation is supplied as an integer,
// so we just rotate/flip it back to the correct orientation based on what we
// are told it currently is
switch( $exif['orientation'] ) {

    // Standard/Normal Orientation (no need to do anything, we'll return true as in theory, it was successful)
    case 1:
        return true;
    // Flipped on the horizontal axis (might do it at some point in the future)
    case 2:
        //By @kormanowsky: imageflip() returns TRUE or FALSE so it's wrong to assign its return value to $final_img
        imageflip( $img_res, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL );
        break;
    // Turned 180 deg
    case 3:
        imageflip( $img_res, IMG_FLIP_BOTH );
        break;
    // Upside-Down
    case 4:
        imageflip( $img_res, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL );
        break;
    // Turned 90 deg to the left and flipped
    case 5:
        imageflip( $img_res, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL );
    // Turned 90 deg to the left
    case 6:
        $img_res = imagerotate( $img_res, -90, 0 );
        break;
    // Turned 90 deg to the right and flipped
    case 7:
        imageflip( $img_res, IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL );
    // Turned 90 deg to the right
    case 8:
        $img_res = imagerotate( $img_res, 90, 0 );
        break;
}
//-- rename original (very ugly, could probably be rewritten, but i can't be arsed at this stage)
$parts = explode( "/", $fileandpath );
$oldname = array_pop( $parts );
$path = implode( '/', $parts );
$oldname_parts = explode( ".", $oldname );
$ext = array_pop( $oldname_parts );
$newname = implode( '.', $oldname_parts ) . '.orig.' . $ext;
rename( $fileandpath, $path . '/' . $newname );
// Save it and the return the result (true or false)
$done = save_image_resource( $img_res, $fileandpath );
return $done;
}
function get_image_resource($file)
{
$img = null;
$p = explode( ".", strtolower( $file ) );
$ext = array_pop( $p );
switch( $ext ) {

    case "png":
        $img = imagecreatefrompng( $file );
        break;
    case "jpg":
    case "jpeg":
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $file );
        break;
    case "gif":
        $img = imagecreatefromgif( $file );
        break;
}
return $img;
}
function save_image_resource($resource, $location)
{
$success = false;
$p = explode( ".", strtolower( $location ) );
$ext = array_pop( $p );
switch( $ext ) {

    case "png":
        $success = imagepng( $resource, $location );
        break;
    case "jpg":
    case "jpeg":
        $success = imagejpeg( $resource, $location );
        break;
    case "gif":
        $success = imagegif( $resource, $location );
        break;
}
return $success;
}
if( !function_exists( 'imageflip' ) ) {
define( "IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL", 1 );
define( "IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL", 2 );
define( "IMG_FLIP_BOTH", 3 );
function imageflip(&$resource, $mode)
{

    if( $mode == IMG_FLIP_VERTICAL || $mode == IMG_FLIP_BOTH )
        $resource = imagerotate( $resource, 180, 0 );
    if( $mode == IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL || $mode == IMG_FLIP_BOTH )
        $resource = imagerotate( $resource, 90, 0 );
}
}
```

however I had some problem with JPEG, because the function read_exif_data supports no JPEG images. I had to make some changes.

Let me know if you had the same problems. I will suggest the edition on Github.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did in my website. I believe this will help you resolve the issue.

The process is done in similar 2 steps:
1. Read orientation
2. Rotate or Flip the image

```
function check_jpeg($f, $fix=false ){
        if ( false !== (@$fd = fopen($f, 'r+b' )) )
        {
                    if (fread($fd,2)==chr(255).chr(216) )
                    {
                                    fseek ( $fd, -2, SEEK_END ); 
                                    if ( fread($fd,2)==chr(255).chr(217) )
                                    {
                                        fclose($fd);
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if ($fix && fwrite($fd,chr(255).chr(217)) )
                                        {                        
                                            fclose($fd);
                                            return true;
                                        } 
                                        fclose($fd);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                                    fclose($fd);
                                    return false;
                    }
        }
        else 
        {
                    return false;
        }
}
function fix_image($photo){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
    check_jpeg($photo, true);
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
    $exif = @exif_read_data($photo);
    echo $exif['Orientation'];
    if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])){
        switch($exif['Orientation']){
                case 8:
                 // means counterclockwise 90
                 $image = @imagerotate($image,90,0);
                 break;
                case 3:
                 $image = @imagerotate($image,180,0); 
                 break;
                case 6:
                 $image = @imagerotate($image,-90,0);
                 break;
            }
        }
        @imagejpeg($image,$photo); 
}
```

Hope this helps