# Get actual image height and width value in PHP

Tags: php

I have used a `PHP` function `getimagesize()` to retrieve image height and width. For some specific image get alternative height and width value of actual image. 
Such as to view those image properties in windows than get image `height: 1600px` and `width: 1200px`, but this `PHP` function shows `height: 1200px` and `width: 1600px`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: show me your getimagesize() function

Comment: @f_anto [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: $image_property = getimagesize($_FILES['person_image']['tmp_name']);

when i print $image_property variable then show height and width but this value does not match my computer image properties

Comment: thanks @Ivar and Jaherul

Comment: you want to get the image size as displayed in the browser and not its original size am I right ?

Comment: it may be orientation issue. see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation

Comment: thanks @Suchit for you suggestion , i also think its orientation related problem, but i could not find any proper solution.
By the Way i see your link and try to solution it.