# PHP - Process vertical image take from iPhone

Tags: php, ios, iphone, image

I have made a site to take a photo, it convert to square and it merge with other image. The site is working fine but I have a problem, a big problem.

The pictures to take from iPhone in vertical really are in horizontal. Then when it convert and it merge the image show wrong rotate :(

Ex: iPhone take a vertical photo:

[image]

Really the vertical photo is:

[image]

This photos when I open from mac is showed fine but when is open from another plataform (win or linux) is showed in horizontal. For this I think that this images contain any data to identify it.

The php code is this: (I think that the code is correct, Just need to put any instruction to recognize the orientation)

```
<?php
          $file = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

          list($x, $y) = getimagesize($file);

          echo "MEDIDAS";
          echo "<br>";
          echo "x: ".$x;
          echo "<br>";
          echo "y: ".$y;
          echo "<br>";


          // horizontal rectangle
          if ($x > $y) {
              $square = $y;              // $square: square side length
              $offsetX = ($x - $y) / 2;  // x offset based on the rectangle
              $offsetY = 0;              // y offset based on the rectangle
              $grados = 270;
              echo "Horizontal rectangle";
          }
          // vertical rectangle
          elseif ($y > $x) {
              $square = $x;
              $offsetX = 0;
              $offsetY = ($y - $x) / 2;
              $grados = 270;
              echo "Vertical rectangle";
          }
          // it's already a square
          else {
              $square = $x;
              $offsetX = $offsetY = 0;
              $grados = 0;
              echo "Cuadrat";
          }

?>
```

Sorry, this issue is very difficult to explain it.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orientation is stored in the exif data. You should extract that information from the image and rotate that image accordingly. Here you can find [some code that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation).
And here you can find the [exif orientation values and their meanings](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Cup. I will try it ;)