# Why does gd library flip my image sideways

Tags: php, image, image-processing, php-gd

I don't know why in my code does my image gets fliped to the left for 90 deg. but only when image is portrait mode height/width > 1

`$fname` is the name of the file stored on disk,
`$ofname` is original name used to get its extension

```
function reduce($fname, $ofname) {

    $originalImagePath = "slike/" . $fname;
    $resizedImagePath = "slike3/" . $fname;

    $allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($ofname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedExtensions)) {
        switch ($fileExtension) {
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
                $originalImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImagePath);
                break;
            case "png":
                $originalImage = imagecreatefrompng($originalImagePath);
                break;
            default:
                echo "Unsupported image format.";
                exit();
        }

    $percent = 0.2;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalImagePath);
    $newWidth = $width * $percent;
    $newHeight = $height * $percent;

    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

    imagecopyresized($resizedImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($resizedImage, $resizedImagePath);

    imagedestroy($originalImage);
    imagedestroy($resizedImage);

    echo 'Resized image saved successfully.';
    }
}
```

I want to make a smaller resolution image and keep my aspect ratio

Comment: I would look into reading the exif orientation data and using the value to determine the ultimate rotation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation